# Create Github repository from API

Tags: git, github, github-api

Please provide working code that creates a Github repository using the API.

I have tried different versions of the following:

```
curl 'https://api.github.com/users/repos?client_id= myusername&client_secret=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcd'
curl -u 'myusername' https://api.github.com/users/repos -d '{"name":"my-new-repo"}'
```

But I always get the following error:

```
"{
  \"message\": \"Bad credentials\",
  \"documentation_url\": \"https://developer.github.com/v3\"
}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works:

(without variables)

```
curl -H "Authorization: token abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcd" 
  --data '{"name":"name-foo"}' https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

(with variables)

```
NAME='name-foo'
TOK='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcd'
BASE='https://api.github.com/'
EXT='user/repos'
URL=$BASE$EXT
curl -H "Authorization: token $TOK" --data "{\"name\":\"$NAME\"}" $URL
```

One can use *personal access tokens* instead of *OAuth*.

The `YOUR_TOKEN` value in the `"Authorization: token YOUR_TOKEN"` section of the `curl` command can be obtained as follows.

1. Upper right corner, click <kbd>User</kbd>
2. <kbd>Settings</kbd>
3. <kbd>Personal Access Tokens</kbd>
4. For scopes, select <kbd>Repos</kbd>.
5. <kbd>Create New Token</kbd>.

For more details, [click here](https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens) and [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#basic-authentication).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it in an organization, creating an `internal` repository:

```sh
curl -X POST 'https://api.github.com/orgs/myorg/repos' \
  --header 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxx' \
  -d '{"name":"myrepo","visibility":"internal"}'
```