# How can I see all the opened merge requests in GitLab using a command?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-api

Is there a git command that can show all the opened merge requests for a repository? I've found how I can see all the branches that were merged into master using: 
`git log --merges --first-parent master \ --pretty=format:"%h %<(10,trunc)%aN %C(white)%<(15)%ar%Creset %C(red bold)%<(15)%D%Creset %s"`, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: AFAIK it cannot be done through the CLI, so you should use either the web interface or Gitlab API.

Comment: Gitlab API certainly can be called from the command line.

Comment: [This is an example of how to call an API with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36755216/7976758) and [here is the API to list merge requests](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/merge_requests.html#list-merge-requests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the tips phd gave me, I've found this command that helped me see all the opened merge request for a single branch that I want:

```
curl -k --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: TOKEN" "https://gitlabhost.com/api/v4/merge_requests?scope=all&state=opened&source_branch=source_branch" > ROOTDIR/opened_merge_requests.txt
```

Considering TOKEN, source_branch and ROOTDIR to be string variables.