# Local repo commit

Tags: bash, git, shell, gitlab

I have to create 100 repos from my local filesystem. Each project directory has to be created as a separate repo.

I have created separate folders for each of my project and created a base repo on Github. I clone it to my local and tried to do push. However I got all these folders as folder on GitHub.

I need each folder to be a new repo.

Comment: You mean to say, your folder structure is like local_repo_folder/github_repo_folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script it such as, for each folder:

- you call the [GitHub API to create a new repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753547/create-github-repository-from-api)
- you initialize a new empty repository in the current folder

  ```
  git init .
  git add .
  git commit -m "first commit for folder x"`
  ```
- you define the remote URL, and push

  ```
  git remote add origin https://github.com/you/folderN
  git push -u origin master
  ```

Comment: I need to create Repo for all my project folders (No.100) . Do I need to create init on all folders. Any scripts can help to complete this task...

Comment: @MariappanMurugan Yes, each project folder would have its own Git repository. Hence the `git init .` in each.